# Compare two Date hours

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

I have a two times:
"02:00" this is hoursValue : minutesValue
"02:00" this is hoursValue : minutesValue

```js
var startTime = new Date().setHours("02:00".split(":")[0]);
console.log(startTime);

var endTime = new Date().setHours("2:00".split(":")[0]);
console.log(endTime);

var compare = startTime === endTime;
console.log(compare)

> 1672965757045
> 1672965757046
> false
```

I noticed that sometimes it returns the different  number of milliseconds.
why this solution is bad and how to compare two hour when first one started from 0 another no.

Comment: Well... it sometimes takes almost 1 ms to execute the first line, so on the second line 1 ms has already passed and you get a different date.

Comment: Execution doesn't need to take 1 ms, the clock just needs to tick over to the next millisecond between calls. In any case, you can just do `new Date().getHours() < '02:00'.split(':')[0]`. You might also parse the time to hours as `parseInt('02:00')` for more syntactic code.

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you just compare the hours directly?

```js
var startTime = new Date();
startTime.setHours("02:00".split(":")[0]);
console.log(startTime);

var endTime = new Date();
endTime.setHours("2:00".split(":")[0]);
console.log(endTime);

var compare = startTime.getHours() === endTime.getHours();
console.log(compare);
```

Comment: Good answer. You don;t even need to `.setHours()` with this answer.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you get a different start and end time is because `console.log()` and any other action takes time. Just get the star and end time, and compare the hours later:

```js
var startTime = new Date();
console.log('introduce a small delay with console log');
var endTime = new Date();
let diff = endTime.valueOf() - startTime.valueOf();
let compare = startTime.getHours() === endTime.getHours();
console.log({
  startTime,
  endTime,
  diff,
  compare
});
```